# Use a DIV's width in If statement in Php file

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

I have a .php file in which I have a layout that I would like to change depending of a div's width. That div is a parent of the following code and is situated in a other file.

```
<?php if ($(".container").width() > 400) { ?>

    <div class="sub-container">
        <div">sidepanel-left</div>
        <div>content</div>
        <div>sidepanel-right</div>
    </div>

<?php } else { ?>

    <div class="sub-container">
        <div>sidepanel-left
                <div>sidepanel-right</div>
        </div>
        <div>content</div>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

That gives me a blank page with only Html, head and body tags.

I'm sure it's a pretty basic code that I need, but I'm just starting in PHP/JS and I'm not sure of what I'm doing -_-

Let me know if you need more information!

Thanks in advance for the help! :)

B.

Comment: It looks like you're thinking of jQuery. PHP doesn't know the width of any DOM elements.

Comment: You can't combine server side code and client side code. PHP doesn't know the width of any element, it's just sending HTML to be rendered. Javascript can detect the width because the elements have been rendered on the page. You shouldn't have that IF statement to output the code. Just send one version. Either update your CSS to handle this layout difference depending on widths, or use some Javascript to do it. I'd handle it with CSS though.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. I read about PHP not knowing the width, but I thought it was only not able to read the size of the windows and not of any element (much to learn indeed).

I know about @media in CSS for adapting the css depending of the width of the window...but how can I use CSS to detect the width of a div/class? thanks!

Comment: For CSS, see [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). They can also be used for "responsivity" to the different dimensions of various devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do this in PHP. What you can do is the following:

From PHP side, output this HTML code:

```
    <div class="container">
        ...
        <div class="sub-container">
            <div>sidepanel-left</div>
            <div>content</div>
            <div>sidepanel-right</div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Then in your HTML page, make sure jquery is loaded, and put this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 

        $('.container').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if ( $this.width() > 400 ) {
                $this.addClass('wide-container');
            }
        });
    }); 
    </script>
```

Then, in your css file you can setup a class for regular container and wide container, and you can also control the styles of subcontainers:

```
    .container {
        // default styles here
    }

    .container.wide-container {
        // override wide container styles
    }

    .container.wide-container > .subcontainer {
        // override subcontainer styles
    }
```

You might use @media queries to achieve similar result, but @media queries can be applied according to the width of the screen, not a particular container.

Comment: Thanks! I will manage something with your code. I don't want to use @media queries because I want the change to be based on the width of a particular div and not the screen. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2970517 +1 This answer is good. Just one thing to note to the OP: It looks like you want to put sidepanel-left and sidepanel-right on top of each other when width < 400, so you may have to give each of those their own id/class so you can move them around.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, only use javascript if there is absolutely no way to get away with pure css and/or media queries. Even though media queries are limited, they will change their values on browser window resize, etc. The code that I wrote will not update container class when browser is resized. To do that, you might need to wrap everything into $(window).on('resize', function(){ ... });